# Easy way to get and modify a .vb file like a text file

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a vb.net application for converting a Data Access Layer classes from Oracle DB oriented to SQL Server DB oriented ,
And i must convert every Oracle oriented class like :
OracleCommand , OracleDataAdapter , OracleDataReader ... 
to it's SQL Server equivalent .

Is there any way to get methods list from .vb file and to get the body of each method from vb application to change it dynamically and create new version of each file ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compile in debug mode, one of the output files is PROGRAMNAME.xml, which contains all the method signatures for the EXE. (Where PROGRAMNAME is the name of your EXE).

You can write a program to edit the .vb files just like any other text file, because they are text files.

Comment: I want to change the method body not the signatures 
:D

Answer (score 0):

Download trial version of Resharper and it will help you to do it with no pain. One month trial should be enough.

VS also has some tools - "Find all references" and "Find and Replace in Files". So, you can Find and replace Oracle... To Sql...

On the other note, why not writing wrappers that will provide DB-agnostic providers for command, transaction, etc. For example, instead of

```
Dim reader As OracleDataReader = OracleCommand.ExecuteReader...
```

Do this

```
Dim reader As IDataReader = MyAgnosticCommand.ExecuteReader...
```

So, if the new boss is coming tomorrow and says, "Oh we need oracle" - you don't have to do it all over again.

Comment: @Walid.Isbaih You need to have your projects in one solution and then you can click "find usages" - it will show all instances where it used. But yes, you will need to use File find and replace for brute replace.